# Java 8 toMap IllegalStateException Duplicate Key

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a file which contains data in the following format

```
1
2
3
```

I want to load this to map as `{(1->1), (2->1), (3->1)}`

This is the Java 8 code,

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map1 = Files.lines(Paths.get(inputFile))
                .map(line -> line.trim())
                .map(Integer::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, x -> 1));
```

I am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key 1
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: What would you like to happen when the file has the same number twice?

Comment: If there is a situation like that, I want to get the number of occurrences as value for that key. So, if say key 2 is occurs 4 times in the file, then it would be (2->4).

Comment: Then you'll need to use this method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-

Comment: Thanks JB, I just found that, I had another test case where the input had duplicates and it was giving that error. Added the logic to increase the number of occurrences.

Comment: I think this question would be better if the sample data actually included a duplicate

Comment: I faced the same issue, isn't the error message misleading ? The error message says duplicate key and prints out the value instead

Comment: @Abhijeet yes, the message is indeed misleading, because it's printing the value while saying "Duplicate key %s". Error message should be something like "Values %s and %s have a duplicate key" or "Duplicate key encountered for value %s and value %s"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The code will run if there are no duplicates in the file.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map1 = Files.lines(Paths.get(inputFile))
            .map(String::trim)
            .map(Integer::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, x -> 1));
```

If there are duplicates use the following code to get the total number of occurrences in the file for that key.

```
Map<Integer, Long> map1 = Files.lines(Paths.get(inputFile))
            .map(String::trim)
            .map(Integer::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, Collectors.counting());
```

Comment: You could do `collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, Collectors.counting()))` which might be clearer than the 3-arg form of `toMap()`. Also, you could also use `String::trim` instead of `line -> line.trim()`.

Comment: @StuartMarks, I am getting the cyclic inference error for Collectors.groupingsBy(x -> x, Collectors.counting()

Comment: Ah, `counting()` accumulates into a `Long`, so you have to change the map declaration to `Map<Integer,Long>`.

Comment: Side comment: `Files.lines` does not automatically close the file - if you do this a lot you could run into a "too many files open" error. You could use a try-with-resources: `try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(...)) { lines.map(String::trim).... }`

Comment: @assylias For future readers, they fixed this in [11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines(java.nio.file.Path)): _The file is closed by closing the stream._

Answer (score 66):

The pramodh's answer is good if you want to map your value to 1. But in case you don't want to always map to a constant, the use of the "merge-function" might help:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map1 = Files.lines(Paths.get(inputFile))
                .map(line::trim())
                .map(Integer::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, x -> 1, (x1, x2) -> x1));
```

The above code is almost the same as posted in the question. But if it encounters a `duplicate key`, instead of throwing an exception, it will **solve it by applying the merge function**, by taking the first value.

Comment: This is much more useful. Thanks @KeyMaker00